# iconv error in xcode 11 with incomplete character or shift sequence at end of buffer

Tags: xcode, xcode11

after installing xcode 11 beta I get the following error
`iconv "incomplete character or shift sequence at end of buffer" error`

while running this custom Build Phase script 
`iconv -f UTF-16LE -t UTF-8 Resources/en.lproj/Localizable.strings > Resources/en.lproj/tmp.strings` any idea what could go wrong here?

Comment: It sounds as if the source file `Localizable.strings` is not properly encoded in UTF-16LE. Validate and fix the encoding, or add the command line argument `-c`. It will simply remove all characters that are not valid UTF-16LE.

Comment: Its not incorrect. It still works with xcode 10 but not xcode 11 I guess it might have to do something with xcode tool chain that is installed with xcode 11 even -c argument is not working.